# List of values from dataframe column where each row has muliple values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
index     column

A         41 13 4 61 12 35

B         16 35 56 24

C         12
```

And I want to end up with a long list of all values like `[41, 13, 4, 61, 12, 35, 16, 35, 56, 24, 12]`

So first I converted that column into a dict with `DataFrame.to_dict()`

And then what I was trying to do was to split each dict value into a list rather than a long string:

```
for key,val in d.items():
    d[key] = val.split[' ']
```

but it's throwing an error: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Then I would proceed to append all the values into a long list. But given the error, I'm suspecting that there is a simpler way that I am missing. Does anyone know what that could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` the column then use `hstack` to flatten

```
np.hstack(df['column'].str.split()).tolist()
```

Alternatively you can use a pure python approach

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*map(str.split, df['column'])))
```

---

```
['41', '13', '4', '61', '12', '35', '16', '35', '56', '24', '12']
```

Comment: Nice one. And how would I change that if I want the values to be `int` instead of string?

Comment: You can simply  cast the values to `int`: Solution 1: `np.hstack(df['column'].str.split()).astype(int).tolist()`. Solution 2: `list(map(int, chain(*map(str.split, df['column']))))`